# How to stop Sublime Text from showing the build time?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

When I build a program in Sublime Text 4, it will always show [Finished in XXXms] at the end of the output(image below). How can I stop that from happening? It's just a little bothersome since I include a timer in all of my small programs that I build in sublime.

[image: Picture of build time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default build system command, you can add `"quiet": true,` to the build system you are using to prevent the `[Finished]` line from appearing. To edit the build system (`.sublime-build` file) you will want to use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit

Comment: Wow look at this [link](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/add-variant-to-existing-build-system/32305/3) I just found a comment of yours from 4 years ago. Thanks for helping out people for so long